# react material-table formik validation in custom edit component

Tags: reactjs, formik, material-table

I'm using react-material-table.
I'm trying to validate the row edit.

Everything works fine for "native" material column. 
But I had to use a custom editComponent for one column rendering an Autocomplete.

```
{
      title: "test",
      field: "foo",
      editComponent: (props) => {


        return (
          <div>
            <Autocomplete

              onChange={(e, v) => this.handleFooChange(props.rowData.id, v)}
              //onChange={(e,v) => props.onChange(v)}
              id="people-company"
              options={[{ id: 1, name: "bar" }, { id: 2, name: "foo" }]}
              getOptionLabel={option => option.name}

              value={props.rowData.foo}
              filterSelectedOptions
              renderInput={params => (
                <TextField
                  {...params}
                  variant="outlined"
                  label="company"
                  placeholder="company"
                  margin="normal"
                  fullWidth
                />
              )}
            />
          </div>
        );
      },
```

My MaterialTable define EditRow and EditField

```
    const FormikMTInput = props => {

  return (
    <Field name={props.columnDef.field}>
      {({ field, form, meta }) => {
        const { name } = field;
        const { errors, setFieldValue } = form;
        //console.log("ShowError", errors);
        const showError = !!getIn(errors, name);

        return (
          <div>
            <MTableEditField
              {...props}
              {...field}
              error={showError}
              onChange={newValue => setFieldValue(name, newValue)}
            />
            {errors[field.name] && (
              <div style={{ color: "#f44336" }}>{errors[field.name]}</div>
            )}
          </div>
        );
      }}
    </Field>
  );
};

const MuiTableEditRow = ({ onEditingApproved, ...props }) => {

  return(
  <Formik

    validate={values => {
      const errors = {};
      if (!values.name) {
        errors.name = "Required";
      }
      if (!values.foo) {
        errors.foo = "Required";
      }

      return errors;
    }}
    initialValues={props.data}
    onSubmit={values => {
      if (values) {
        if (values.name.length > 2 && values.foo)
          onEditingApproved(props.mode, values, props.data);
      }
    }}
    render={({ submitForm }) => (
      <MTableEditRow {...props} onEditingApproved={submitForm} />
    )}
  />
)};
  <MaterialTable
      title="Editable Preview"
      columns={this.state.columns}
      data={this.state.data}
      components={{
        EditRow: MuiTableEditRow,
        EditField: FormikMTInput
      }}
    />
```

FormikMTInput is well fired on "default" columns. It is not the case for the overwrited editComponent. How can I pass errors to this column?

Here the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mendeleev-6z42i?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the current value differs from the rowData value.
So change `value={props.rowData.foo}` to `value={props.value}` in the autocomplete, to get the correct value. Previously, the rowData never changed on edit because the row still had the data until you save it.

Additionally, you should pass the already transformed value to the onChange function and not the event like this: `onChange={v => props.onChange(v.target.value)}`.

`if (!id || id === undefined) return;` is equal to `if (!id) return;`because !id returns true for undefined.

Last but not least, you are mutating your state data in

```
var myData = this.state.data;
   myData.forEach(d => {
      if (d.id === id) {
      d.foo = v;
    }
  });
```

which is a no-go. Change it to:

```
handleFooChange(id, v) {
    if (!id) return;
    const myData = this.state.data.map(d => d.id === id ? {...d, foo: v} : d);
    this.setState({ data: myData });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser... Can you tell me how I should write the onChange (not onChange={v => props.onChange(v.target.value)} ). Also, has foo is a custom editComponent it is not fired has FormikMTInput.

Comment: Because it will generate this error: Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the method `isDefaultPrevented` on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is a no-op function.

Comment: If you change these two lines:  onChange={v => props.onChange(v.target.value)}
                  value={props.value}, it fires.

Comment: I'm sorry, I removed the onChange={(e, v) => this.handleFooChange(props.rowData.id, v)} and change the  value to  value={props.value} and it is still not fired

Comment: Using onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}  value={props.value} only set props.value to 0 for all selected values in Autocomplete or undefined if nothing selected!

Comment: I see, its because you override the editComponent, the default editComponent (the one you wrap with Formik) will thus not be rendered. You need to supply the autocomplete with formik in the column editComponent prop.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention... How can I supply autocomplete with formik?